# generate select options using php arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a "state" category select that displays one of 4 "carrier" selects based on the state chosen. I want php to populate the "carrier" selects with their respective options. I have searched stack and I'm sure there are several answers out there, but due to my novice php status I have a hard time understanding the logic. That being said, the current php I have is what I'm instructed to use/recycle and does not reflect my php skills. I really need help on this one guys!

Here's a fiddle (minus the php): http://fiddle.jshell.net/prxmeo9z/

The HTML (WITH THE PHP):

```
    <div class="dropdown-box">
                        <select name="state_select" id="state_select">
                            <option selected disabled>Choose a state</option>
                            <option value="1">Connecticut</option>
                            <option value="2">New Hampshire</option>
                            <option value="3">New Jersey</option>
                            <option value="4">New York</option>
                        </select>
</div>
        <br />

<div id="select-div1" class="select-div">
        <select name="conn_select" id="carrier_select1"  class="carr-hide">
            <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - Conn</option>
            <option value="1">
             <? 
            $options = '';
foreach($company_arry as $company) {
    $options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";
}
echo $options;
?>
            </option>
        </select>
</div>

<div id="select-div" class="select-div">                      
        <select name="nh_select" id="carrier_select2" class="carr-hide">
            <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NH</option>
            <option value="2">
            <? 
            $options = '';
foreach($company_arryNH as $company) {
    $options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";
}
echo $options;
?>
            </option>
        </select>
</div>

<div id="select-div" class="select-div">                       
        <select name="nj_select" id="carrier_select3" class="carr-hide">
            <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NJ</option>
            <option value="3">
             <? 
            $options = '';
foreach($company_arryNJ as $company) {
    $options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";
}
echo $options;
?>
            </option>
        </select>
</div>

<div id ="select-div" class="select-div">                        
        <select name="ny_select" id="carrier_select4" class="carr-hide">
            <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NY</option>
            <option value="4">
            <? 
            $options = '';
foreach($company_arry as $company) {
    $options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";
}
echo $options;
?>
            </option>
        </select>

</div>
```

The JS/JQuery:

```
function optionCheck() {
    var i, len, optionVal, helpDiv,
        selectOptions = document.getElementById("state_select");

    // loop through the options in case there
    // are multiple selected values
    for (i = 0, len = selectOptions.options.length; i < len; i++) {

        // get the selected option value
        optionVal = selectOptions.options[i].value;

        // find the corresponding help div
        helpDiv = document.getElementById("carrier_select" + optionVal);
        //selectDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("select-div");

        // move on if we didn't find one
        if (!helpDiv) { continue; }

        // set CSS classes to show/hide help div
        if (selectOptions.options[i].selected) {
            helpDiv.className = "conn_select nh_select nj_select ny_select";
            $(helpDiv).addClass("dropdown-box");
        } else {
            helpDiv.className = "carr-hide";
            //$(".select-div").addClass("carr-hide");

        }
    }    
}

// alternative method of binding the onchange handler
document.getElementById("state_select").onchange = optionCheck;
```

The PHP file I'm including:

```
<?
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT gia_survey_allyears_company.Name, gia_survey_allyears_matrix.* FROM `gia_survey_allyears_matrix` 
                    left join gia_survey_allyears_company on gia_survey_allyears_matrix.CompanyID = gia_survey_allyears_company.ID
                    WHERE gia_survey_allyears_matrix.CompanyID=".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['id']))."");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

$qu_arry = array(   'Q1'=>'N/A','Q2'=>'N/A','Q3'=>'N/A','Q4'=>'N/A',
                    'Q5'=>'N/A','Q6'=>'N/A','Q7'=>'N/A','Q8'=>'N/A',
                    'Q9'=>'N/A','Q10'=>'N/A','Q11'=>'N/A','Q12'=>'N/A',
                    'Q13'=>'N/A','Q14'=>'N/A','Q15'=>'N/A','Q16'=>'N/A');

$quavg_arry = array(    'Q1'=>'N/A','Q2'=>'N/A','Q3'=>'N/A','Q4'=>'N/A',
                    'Q5'=>'N/A','Q6'=>'N/A','Q7'=>'N/A','Q8'=>'N/A',
                    'Q9'=>'N/A','Q10'=>'N/A','Q11'=>'N/A','Q12'=>'N/A',
                    'Q13'=>'N/A','Q14'=>'N/A','Q15'=>'N/A','Q16'=>'N/A');

$holdarry = array(  'Agents'=>'N/A','RankOutOf'=>'N/A','Rank'=>'N/A','Score'=>'N/A',
                    'Avg'=>'N/A','AvgAllScore'=>'N/A','AvgAllQuestion'=>'N/A',
                    'ComAvg'=>'N/A','Q1-16'=>$qu_arry,'Q1-16Avg'=>$quavg_arry);

$company['2003'] = $holdarry;
$company['2004'] = $holdarry;
$company['2005'] = $holdarry;
$company['2006'] = $holdarry;
$company['2007'] = $holdarry;
$company['2008'] = $holdarry;
$company['Name']= $row['Name'];
$company['State']= $row['State'];

do {
// Show Scores for question
$qu_arry = array(   'Q1'=>round($row['Q2-0'],1),'Q2'=>round($row['Q2-1'],1),'Q3'=>round($row['Q3-0'],1),'Q4'=>round($row['Q3-1'],1),
                    'Q5'=>round($row['Q3-2'],1),'Q6'=>round($row['Q4-0'],1),'Q7'=>round($row['Q4-1'],1),'Q8'=>round($row['Q5-0'],1),
                    'Q9'=>round($row['Q5-1'],1),'Q10'=>round($row['Q5-2'],1),'Q11'=>round($row['Q6-0'],1),'Q12'=>round($row['Q6-1'],1),
                    'Q13'=>round($row['Q7-0'],1),'Q14'=>round($row['Q7-1'],1),'Q15'=>round($row['Q8-0'],1),'Q16'=>round($row['Q8-1'],1));

    $company[$row['Year']]= array(  'Agents'=>$row['total'],
                                    'RankOutOf'=>'',
                                    'Rank'=>$row['Rank'],
                                    'Score'=>round($row['QAvg'],1),
                                    'Q1-16'=>$qu_arry,
                                    'Q1-16Avg'=>'');

    $sqlStateYear = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gia_survey_allyears_matrix` WHERE CompanyID=0 and `State`='".$row['State']."' and `Year`='".$row['Year']."'");
    $rowStateYear = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlStateYear);

    do {

$company[$row['Year']]['Q1-16Avg'] = 
              array('Q1'=>round($rowStateYear['Q2-0'],1),'Q2'=>round($rowStateYear['Q2-1'],1),
                    'Q3'=>round($rowStateYear['Q3-0'],1),'Q4'=>round($rowStateYear['Q3-1'],1),
                    'Q5'=>round($rowStateYear['Q3-2'],1),'Q6'=>round($rowStateYear['Q4-0'],1),
                    'Q7'=>round($rowStateYear['Q4-1'],1),'Q8'=>round($rowStateYear['Q5-0'],1),
                    'Q9'=>round($rowStateYear['Q5-1'],1),'Q10'=>round($rowStateYear['Q5-2'],1),
                    'Q11'=>round($rowStateYear['Q6-0'],1),'Q12'=>round($rowStateYear['Q6-1'],1),
                    'Q13'=>round($rowStateYear['Q7-0'],1),'Q14'=>round($rowStateYear['Q7-1'],1),
                    'Q15'=>round($rowStateYear['Q8-0'],1),'Q16'=>round($rowStateYear['Q8-1'],1));
$company[$row['Year']]['AvgAllScore'] = round($rowStateYear['QAvg'],1);
$company[$row['Year']]['RankOutOf'] = $rowStateYear['total'];
    } while ($rowStateYear = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlStateYear));

// END
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));
function fnRake($rake) {
    if ($rake==11 || $rake==12 || $rake==13) {
        $i=$rake;
    }else {
        $i = substr($rake,strlen($rake)-1,1);
    }
    switch ($i) {
        case 1:
            $add =  "st";
        break;
        case 2:
            $add =  "nd";
        break;
        case 3:
            $add =  "rd";
        break;
        case 11:
            $add =  "th";
        break;
        case 12:
            $add =  "th";
        break;
        case 13:
            $add =  "th";
        break;
        default:
            $add =  "th";
        break;
    }
    if ($rake=="N/A") {
        return $rake;
    }else{
        return $rake."<sup>$add</sup>";
    }
}
?>
```

Some additional PHP at the start of my html:

```
    $state = new state;
$state_arry = $state->state_options("NY");

//For Connecticut
$sqlCT = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gia_survey_allyears_company` WHERE `State`='CT' and `show`='Y' order by Name");
//For New York
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gia_survey_allyears_company` WHERE `State`='NY' and `show`='Y' order by Name");
//For New Jersey
$sqlNJ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gia_survey_allyears_company` WHERE `State`='NJ' and `show`='Y' order by Name");
//For New Hampshire
$sqlNH = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gia_survey_allyears_company` WHERE `State`='NH' and `show`='Y' order by Name");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

//For New York
do {
    $company_arry[]=array('Name'=>$row['Name'],'Id'=>$row['ID']);
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql));

//For New Jersey
do {
    $company_arryNJ[]=array('Name'=>$row['Name'],'Id'=>$row['ID']);
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlNJ));

//For New Jersey
do {
    $company_arryNH[]=array('Name'=>$row['Name'],'Id'=>$row['ID']);
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlNH));

//For Connecticut
do {
    $company_arryCT[]=array('Name'=>$row['Name'],'Id'=>$row['ID']);
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlCT));

$total = count($company_arry);
$col1 = round($total/2);
$col2 = $total-1
```

;

THIS PHP GENERATES A LIST THAT I NEED IN THE NY CARRIER SELECT(AS AN EXAMPLE):

```
 <? 
            for ($i1=0; $i1<= $col1; $i1++) { 
                echo "<a href=\"company.php?id=".$company_arry[$i1]['Id']."\">".$company_arry[$i1]['Name']."</a><br>";
            } 
            ?>
```

Comment: That's nice and all, but... exactly WHAT is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, I need to modify that last PHP code( the sample) to generate options NOT hrefs...and I have no clue how. Or if that's even the right solution?

Comment: it's just text. how hard is it to change `"<a href=..."` to `"<option ..."`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will fix it

```
$options = '';
foreach($company_arry as $company) {
    $options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";
}
echo $options;
```

Comment: This works! Each state has a different list of carriers though, and my "$sql" variable only queries all companies in  NY at the moment. So should I duplicate the variable for each state? or is there a better way?

Comment: @StevenSerrano, do all databases have the same layout? So just `name` and `Id`.

Comment: Yes. Down the road the user will click an additional button that will take the state and carrier and pull table data based on the state and carriers unique ID's (carrier ID's already exist). I have updated the post to reflect the changes I've made to the HTML section and "additional PHP" section. Is this a good solution?