# How to populate a drop down box with .csv column using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, dropdown

I have a drop down box that I want filled with the first column in a .csv file. I've been trying to use PHP from sites I found online. I got it where the last name in the column displays but that is it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```php
<select name="genre" class="bl-select">
    <option value="">Categories</option>
    <?php
        $fileHandle = fopen("https://thattimelessbookshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cats.csv", "r");
        while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $cats = $row[0];
        }
    ?>

    <option value= "<?php echo $cats; ?>"><?php echo $cats; ?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generate select options using php arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304788/generate-select-options-using-php-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ending your `while` loop too early, do it like this:

```
<select name="genre" class="bl-select">
<?php
    $fileHandle = fopen("https://thattimelessbookshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cats.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $cats = $row[0];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cats;?>"><?php echo $cats;?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```